# How to append dictionary to csv without appending keys

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, scrapy

I have a dictionary features = {'feature1' : 'hi', 'feature2': 'second feature', 'feature3': 'third feature'}. I need to save it to a csv file. But this dictionary gets renewed in each iteration and a new dictionary is appended to existing csv file. I am using it in scrapy.

```
class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_1.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/otomobil/', 'parse'),
        # ('/category/', 'parse_category'),
    ]

    def parse(self,response):


                            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self,response):
        # print("hi here")
        features = {}
        features["ad_url"] = response.request.url
        #filling feature dictionary
        df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(features , orient='index')
        df = df.transpose()
        df.to_csv("result.csv",mode = 'a', index = False)
```

The problem is that this saves dictionary to csv along with key as well. I am attaching the picture of excel sheet here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EC1HI.png)

Intuitively speaking header should be filled only once at the top and not every time in every other row. How do I do that?

Comment: you can remove pandas and use scrapy default csv exporter

Comment: @wishmaster kindly provide more context for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Myspider(SitemapSpider):
    name = 'spidername'
    sitemap_urls = ['https://www.arabam.com/sitemap/otomobil_1.xml']
    sitemap_rules = [
        ('/otomobil/', 'parse'),
        # ('/category/', 'parse_category'),
    ]
    custom_settings = {'FEED_FORMAT':'csv','FEED_URI':'FILEname.csv'}

    def parse(self,response):


        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

    def parse_dir_contents(self,response):
        # print("hi here")
        item = {}
        item["ad_url"] = response.request.url
        yield item
```

to run it `scrapy crawl spidername`

Comment: AttributeError: 'FeedExporter' object has no attribute 'slot'

Comment: try running it `scrapy crawl spidername -o test.csv`

Comment: its not a scrapy project per say. I created a python file and added commands at the end of script to run it.

Comment: The problem was my csv was open.